# Can we use both PrimeNg and Material in the same Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng

I'm already using `PrimeNg` and `PrimeIcons` along with some other UI libraries in my Angular project.

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^14.1.1",
  },
```

Things are working absolutely fine till here. But today I decided to install `Material` also in my project. The moment I ran this installation command:

`ng add @angular/material`

I got this error:

```
$ ng add @angular/material
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@14.2.2.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@14.2.2 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: primeng@14.1.1
npm ERR! Found: primeicons@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/primeicons
npm ERR!   primeicons@"^6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer primeicons@"^5.0.0" from primeng@14.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/primeng
npm ERR!   primeng@"^14.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: primeicons@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/primeicons
npm ERR!   peer primeicons@"^5.0.0" from primeng@14.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/primeng
npm ERR!     primeng@"^14.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/xpert/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xpert/.npm/_logs/2022-09-24T10_10_51_005Z-debug-0.log
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

I think Material has some conflict with Primeicons. At this moment I'm not sure whether I should research on how to get this resolved or just forget about Material and live with PrimeNg. Please pitch in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they both should work fine, but using both primeng and material at the same doesn't make much sense.

I have seen projects having both primeng and material.

Answer (score 0):

Before running `ng add @angular/material` you have upgraded version of the `primeicons` package, which caused the problem because (as the error message says) PrimeNG depends on PrimeIcons v5 at the moment.

In this particular case PrimeIcons v6 is pretty much compatible with v5, so you can add a peer dependency override:

###### package.json

```json
{
  ...
  "overrides": {
    "primeng": {
      "primeicons": "$primeicons" // means: use the version from the project instead of the one that the package actually depends on
    }
  }
}
```